# Multiplication of a logical matrix with a vector that contains strings in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

Currently I am working on a python problem in which i do have a matrix (a) and a vector (b) which i would like to combine to a new matrix:

```
a= np.array([[1,0,1],[1,1,0]])
b=['a','b','c']
Desired_output = [['a',0,'c'],['a','b',0]]
```

This is therefore basically the multiplication of the matrix and the vector. However due to the fact that the vector also contains strings, it is not possible to just multiply them in python. Could somebody provide me with a solution to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NumPy` isn't really suited for this, since you're also working with lists of strings. Here's one approach using a list comprehension and [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

a = [[1,0,1],[1,1,0]]
b = ['a','b','c']

[[j if not j else k for j, k in zip(i,cycle(b))] for i in a]
# [['a', 0, 'c'], ['a', 'b', 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is by adding a leading zero to `b` as

```
b=np.array([0,'a','b','c'])
```

Then your desired output will be,

```
Desired_output = np.array([ b[(np.arange(len(v))+1)*v] for v in a ])
```